# How to edit android manifest for android apk and rebuild it for chrome app

Tags: android, webrtc, android-manifest, apktool

I am trying to edit `AndroidManifest.xml` for [chrome app](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/chrome/chrome-98-0-4758-101-release/) using `apktool`

Using the below command to decompile the jar, I am able to get the AndroidManifest.xml file and edit file to remove `android:allowAudioPlaybackCapture="false"` attribute from `application` node.

```xml
    <application android:allowAudioPlaybackCapture="false" android:allowBackup="true" android:appComponentFactory="org.chromium.chrome.browser.base.SplitCompatAppComponentFactory" android:backupAgent="org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeBackupAgent" android:fullBackupOnly="false" android:icon="@drawable/APKTOOL_DUPLICATE_drawable_0x7f08022c" android:label="@string/APKTOOL_DUPLICATE_string_0x7f1401e0" android:largeHeap="false" android:manageSpaceActivity="@string/APKTOOL_DUPLICATE_string_0x7f1405e9" android:name="org.chromium.chrome.browser.base.SplitChromeApplication" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/APKTOOL_DUPLICATE_xml_0x7f180025" android:restoreAnyVersion="true" android:roundIcon="@drawable/APKTOOL_DUPLICATE_drawable_0x7f08022d" android:supportsRtl="true" android:zygotePreloadName="org.chromium.content_public.app.ZygotePreload">
```

```sh
apktool d google-chrome-98-0-4758-101.apk
```

But when I trying to build again using below command I get following error

```sh
apktool b google-chrome-98-0-4758-101
```

```java
brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = 1): [/var/folders/dk/1p87jm1d4c1c7rq4s385xfqc0000gn/T/brut_util_Jar_44412591478507968185529954203449703541.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 23, --target-sdk-version, 23, --max-sdk-version, 23, --max-res-version, 23, --version-code, 475810110, --version-name, 98.0.4758.101, --no-version-vectors, -F, /var/folders/dk/1p87jm1d4c1c7rq4s385xfqc0000gn/T/APKTOOL503548586151793248.tmp, -e, /var/folders/dk/1p87jm1d4c1c7rq4s385xfqc0000gn/T/APKTOOL1736943765463305431.tmp, -0, arsc, -I, /apktool/framework/1.apk, -S, /androidrtc/ChromeApk/google-chrome-98-0-4758-101/res, -M, /androidrtc/ChromeApk/google-chrome-98-0-4758-101/AndroidManifest.xml]
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend doing that. There is a reason why Google requires you to sign the APK/AAB files before uploading, and that is to prevent tampering like you are doing here.

At most, if you want to use Chrome in your app, your best bet is to use [Chrome Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/).

Comment: Agreed @oliver but the application I am working on has to record browser audio as a feature. So was just finding ways to see how I can achieve it.

Comment: Have you considered using WebViews instead? That could yield more promising results. Again, hacking an APK is definitely not going to achieve what you are hoping.